# Get selected value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a rather different structure of HTML and I am trying to get the selected value of a dropdown list as seen in the below code:

```
<div class="quantityDropdown quantityDropdown-cartItem">
    <select id="qtySelect-61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421" class="cart-quantity-picker"
            data-orderitem="61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My code returns `null`.

I want to get 2 as my value. As you can see, there's no value in the `selected` attribute.

```
var quantity = document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select").getAttribute("selected");
```

**How do I get the value 2 that's outside the option tag?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: No, mine is different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the value of the selected item:

```
quantity = document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select").value;
```

However if you want the actual content of the selected item (i.e. the text shown) outside of the option tag, use:

```
var quantity = document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select")[document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select").selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Simply using :checked does the trick for the currently selected option, then use .textContent to get its text content

Answer (score 6):

You should get the option tag, like this:

```
var quantity = document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select option:checked");
```

You could use **checked** also for checkbox and radio.

Answer (score 2):

To get the selected option value you need to use two properties on the select element: `options` and `selectedIndex` to get the html option element, then you can get the value.

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.cart-quantity-picker')

console.log('selectedIndex', dropdown.selectedIndex)
console.log('options', dropdown.options)
console.log('selected', dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value)
```

```html
<div class="quantityDropdown quantityDropdown-cartItem">
  <select id="qtySelect-61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421" class="cart-quantity-picker" data-orderitem="61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select").selectedIndex`

Answer (score 1):

in case you need the get the 'value' :

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("qtySelect-61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421");
var selValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

But if you want to get the **text** ΝΟΤ the **value** , you do:

```
 var dropdown = document.getElementById("qtySelect-61224b70-7b26-11e6-91d5-6921d6fe7421");
    var selText = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the value you can use

```
document.querySelector('#qtySelect option:checked').value;
```

For getting the actual text inside the option you can use

```
document.querySelector('#qtySelect option:checked').text;
```